# Comparing the run-time type of a generic type

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, reflection, entity-framework-4

I want to get all the ObjectSet's that start with, say, the word "Foo". I've written the code below but it does not step into the if construct.

```
foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(context))
            {
                if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(ObjectSet<>))
                {
                   // It doesn't step here even though 
                   // prop.PropertyType is an ObjectSet`1...
```

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect `prop.PropertyType` is actually `ObjectSet<X>` for some `X`. You probably want something like:

```
if (prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
    prop.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ObjectSet<>))
```

Comment: How would I say: `prop.GetValue(context) as ObjectSet<>`?

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2: You wouldn't, I'm afraid. What would you want to do with it afterwards? You could cast it to `ObjectQuery`... or call methods with reflection or dynamic typing.